# XPages terrible slowleness in DDE after adding several jars ... is it standard behaviour?

Tags: xpages

I have a quite large xpages project and now I have added some jars to the projects (9 jars via project explorer). After adding these jars to classpath cause that saving every xpage or custom control in DDE takes up do 25 seconds which is crazy (I have a quite fast iCore7 computer, 8GB RAM and working on local Domino server running on my laptop ... all latest 8.5.3).

When I remove these jars from classpath, the save time is back and below 1 sec. Adding these jars to classpath increases the save time up to 25 seconds. Is it normal behaviour? How to avoid this while still using jars?

Comment: We did have a similar problem here, I will ask if we managed to solve and answer if I can.

Comment: We also add JARs to our NSF files but it doesn't degrade the performance. How do you add JARs to the database? We create a `lib` folder inside `WebContent\WEB-INF` folder and put the JARs in their and then add those JARs to Libraries in Java Build Path of the database.

Comment: The same way ... Application contains 30 xpages, 60 controls, 15 JS libraries anf few CSS and many JAVA code in project explorer mostly used as ManagedBeans and related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store Jars in an NSF file the Notes/Domino has to detach them to add them to the classpath before compiling code. This is done each time they are called and if they are on the server then it has to transfer them to the client before detaching.

On a couple of small jars this isn't an issue (depending on frequency of being used). But if you have a large number of jars being called often you should instead put them into the "lib/ext" folder (eg.  c:\notes\jvm\lib\ext).

This way they only get loaded into memory once when the Client/server starts up.

Let me know if this is what is happening and I will see if an SPR exists.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this delay is on every xpage or control even though that jars are not used there. But I understand that on save the DDE builds workspace and recompiles everything (at least it looks like observing the messages in DDE) But slow down is terrible. lib/ext folder is not an option here as I cant imagine how will maintain this on several customers servers in production with no access to filesystem

Comment: What you said is only true for regular applications, xpages are compiled and run server side. A browser wont run java code unless you are making an applet wich is not the case.

Comment: I would still recommend putting them into the lib/ext folder to at least rule this out as being the cause. @GabrielNetto even if the code is compiled server side, embedded Jars are detached from the NSF before the compiling takes place. The overhead may be lower in XPages vs server/web agents, but it doesn't go away.

Comment: but it wont change anything adding it to the lib/ext and that is not a reasonable answer when you working with xpages where machines wont even have notes installed in them. Simply wont matter.

Comment: There is a known performance hit when you have jars embedded in an NSF, which is why we recommend the lib/ext. He should at least rule that out. As for machines that don't have Notes installed on them, you put the Jars into the lib/ext folder on the Domino server.

Comment: Trying to add to domino lib/ext might actually make a difference assuming you can use them in a xpage the same way you do when you add them in nsf itself. But I do wonder if you actually understand how an xpage work.

Comment: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_in_the_Notes_Client-Security#jvm%2Flib%2Fext

Comment: Gabriel, Simon's recommendation is sound. There's a better place to put the JARs if they're actually Eclipse plugins; otherwise, /lib/ext is definitely the ideal location.

Answer (score 1):

Talked with the guys here developing an application that had a similar problem. They said that a particular jar was causing the whole site to slow it down. Maybe you can try adding them individually and see which one is causing the application to slow down.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is caused by transferring the JAR's from the server to the client (as Simon O'Doherty described) you might consider developing in a local replica of the application.

I always work that way for larger apps: develop in a local replica, build or clean that local replica then refresh the application on the (local or remote) Domino server.

Another tip: if you develop this way you can also get a big performance gain if you replace your HDD with an SSD.

Comment: I have a local server running on my machine, its quite fast turnaround except of this ... I was considering developing on local replica but have have to replicate all the time with server its quite slow process ...

Answer (score 0):

I did interesting observation here. Based on Simon D'Oherty advice I moved all jar files to lib/ext and suddenly there is no delay when saving xpage or control. When I put even one jar back to database, there is a delay with 'Building workspace' message. When moving all to lib/ext there is no 'Bulding workspace' message and delay anymore. But working this way is rather crappy as all developers and servers running application must keep all these jars which is almost imposible to maintain. IBM should fix this in database!!

Comment: Are these public jars that I could download for testing? If so I will create an SPR for it. Otherwise open a PMR for it (if you are able to).

Comment: They are public ... base is set of jars required for MongoDB connectivity + some others ...I'm not able to open PMR unfortunately.

Comment: OK I put in 16 Jars into a database. Created an XPage which called a couple of methods and then saved it. No lag in saving. I tried the Jars in file resources + Web-inf/jars folder. So I can't seem to easily reproduce. If you want to post a sample somewhere that reproduces the issue I can create an SPR from it (once reproduced).

Comment: well entire application consist of 30 xpages, 60 controls, 15 JS libraries and few CSS(which also involved in bulding workspace process) and many JAVA code in project explorer mostly used as ManagedBeans and related code(cca. 60 classes/files)